# How can I size columns so that one column has a min-width and the other has as much space to fit its contents as possible?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm building an interface where there are some cards that the user can click to see the detail panel.

The detail panel has a minimum of 900px and it should fit to this remaining space between cards and detail panel.

The cards column should display a max of cards per row and they must have a fixed width.

[image: How to increase details to fit this space?]

```css
main{
  display:flex;
  max-width:calc(100vw - 20px);
  background:green;
  padding:10px;
  justify-content:center;
}

.card{
  width:180px;
  height:240px;
  background:blue;
  margin:10px;
}
aside{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  width:fit-content;
}
.card-detail{
  background:red;
  padding:10px;
  width:100%;
  min-width:900px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <aside>
    <div class="card">
      Card
    </div>
        <div class="card">
      Card
    </div>
        <div class="card">
      Card
    </div>
        <div class="card">
      Card
    </div>
        <div class="card">
      Card
    </div>
  </aside>
  <div class="card-detail">
    Detail
  </div>
</main>
```

I also made a CodePen where I'm trying to solve this:

https://codepen.io/williamxsp/pen/XWNyRqJ

Comment: You have established conflicting requirements. If `.card-detail` always expands to take up as much space as possible then it will by default always shrink the `aside` until it is a single column of `.card`s. In general you cannot place a dynamically-sized container that wraps its inner elements next to an expanding container without the dynamically-sized container always producing a single column of elements.

Comment: @pretzelhammer do you have any advice about how to achieve this requirement? `.card-detail` only need to fit this blank space between these columns.

Should I use Js?

Comment: Could you use CSS Media Queries, hard code the widths depending on the browser window size.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your problem with `flex-shrink`. Here's what I did to fix your problem.

```css
main{
  display:flex;
  max-width:calc(100vw - 20px);
  flex:0 3 100%;
  background:green;
  padding:10px;
  justify-content:center;
}


aside{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  flex-shrink:2;
}
.card{
  width:180px;
  height:240px;
  background:blue;
  margin:10px;
}

.card-detail{
  background:red;
  padding:10px;
  flex-basis:calc(100vw - 55px);
  width:calc(100vw - 55px);
  flex-shrink:1;
}
@media screen and (max-width:991px) {
  main {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
  }
  .card-detail {
    max-width:100%;
  }
}
```

Also I will give you this https://fatihhayrioglu.com/yenilenmis-flex-modulu/ so that you could see the details of flex-boxes)